# Unable to login into WSO2 APIM portals using tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

When I try to login into WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 /carbon with another tenant different that carbon.super (admin) it is not possible.

I have deployed APIM + IS as Key managerand created the new tenants in IS. I´m able to see the new tenants into APIM carbon portal using admin.

If I use admin@test.com the login fail.

---

### --- WSO2 APIM logs: ---
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION

If I try to login into /devportal using another tenant it will login using carbon.super.

---

### --- WSO2 APIM logs: ---
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.tenant.resource.manager.TenantAwareAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver} - Loading configuration context for tenant domain: test.com
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.tenant.resource.manager.TenantAwareAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver} - Configuration store is disabled. Super tenant configuration will be used for the tenant domain: test.com

Could you help me with this issue ?

Note:
WSO2 APIM 3.2.0
WSO2 IS 5.10.0

Thank you for your time!

Best regards,
Frank

Comment: This WARN log has nothing to do with the error you have. You may need to add user core debug logs to get more info

Comment: https://medium.com/nadees-tech-stories/enable-some-useful-debug-logs-on-wso2-products-usercore-ldap-connection-pooling-and-ssl-debug-b7fbedb6a5d

Comment: HI @BuddhimaUdaranga, I updated the log4j2.properties file with "log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG". The logs are the same. When I try to login into apim/carbon the error is "ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION" . The tenants are visibel in the apim but unable to login. Where should I look next ? Thanks you for your time!

Comment: If I try to login in /devportal the following error and warn show up.

API-M Logs:

WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.tenant.resource.manager.TenantAwareAxis2ConfigurationContextObserver} - Configuration store is disabled. Super tenant configuration will be used for the tenant domain: test.com
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.factory.KeyManagerHolder} - Key Manager Resident Key Manager already initialized in tenant test.com

Comment: When I login into /devportal with admin the following debug log show up "DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.dao.OpenIDUserRPDAO} - RP: apim_publisher of user: admin@carbon.super not found in the database".  Not found ?!?!?